# keytool no longer prompts for key password

Tags: .net, maui, keytool

I'm new to `keytool` and following the steps on this page [.NET MAUI Android target publishing/archiving](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4377).  I successfully created a keystore but upon attempting to use it in publishing the app via `dotnet publish -f:<target_framework> -c:Release` at the very end I got the same error in this article: [jarsigner.exe exited with code 1 error in .NET MAUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74780424/jarsigner-exe-exited-with-code-1-error-in-net-maui-app).

Trying to resolve that, I found this article: [What is the significance of "key password" in keystore using keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239587/what-is-the-significance-of-key-password-in-keystore-using-keytool).  So, assuming I got something wrong, I started over -- deleted the keystore and created a new one.

But the second time, it did not prompt for the "key password" at the end; i.e., it did **not** display this prompt:

```
Enter key password for <my-app> //Why this password is required???
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

It did all the rest (see command output at bottom), but that second prompt never appears; only the first time I ran `keytool` and created the very first keystore.  So, I'm not sure what's next.  Do I just ignore that it doesn't prompt for that and **not** include that in my key info?  So, in the below, I would **exclude** the `<AndroidSigningKeyPass/>` entry?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
        <AndroidSigningKeyStore>key.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>keystore password</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>alias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>key password</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image: keytool command output]

Comment: I just found this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords about how to charge either password. But, is it weird that it no longer prompts the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  There are **two** `keytool.exe` installed with VS 2022: One in `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin` the other in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin`.

I managed to use the one from the `Eclipse` folder the first time -- which prompts for both `keystore password` AND `key password` and produces a proprietary (non-PKCS12) format keystore.  The second and subsequent times, I managed to use the one in the `Microsoft` folder -- which prompts **only** for the `keystore password` and produces a PKCS12-compliant keystore.